# Part with/from/away

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm confused between part with and part from. What is the rule behind their usage? How do they differ exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **part from**[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/part+from)
>
> part from someone: *to leave someone*.
>
> I just hate parting from you.
>
> I must part from her now.

**part with** ([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/part-with)

part with something:  *to give something to someone although you would prefer to keep it*

I don’t want to part with any of my books.

Answer (score 5):

I look at is as a difference in relationship.

You 'part with' something that you possess:

> I could be persuaded to part with this pocket watch for $30".

You 'part from' something or a group:

> I must part from you for now but I count the hours until I return".